# VBA - my function takes an arument ByRef instaed of ByVal

Tags: vba, office365

I am encounting a strange situation. I am using MS Access Office 365 on Windows 10.

A parameter of caller is changed. It means strBase treated as ByRef.

```
Public Function AvailableDirPath(strBase As String) As String
' Find non existing folder path.
'   strBase : folder path that a folder is created.
'   Return: Full system path for the directory

    Dim bFound As Boolean: bFound = Falase
    
    Do Until FolderExists(strBase) = False
        ' The ParentFolderPath returns full path of parent folder. 
        strBase = ParentFolderPath(strBase) & "\" & (Int(99999 * Rnd) + 10000)
    Loop
    

    AvailableDirPath = strBase

End Function
```

The caller side is just below.

```
Dim txtPath As String: txtPath = "C:\windows\temp\MSACCESS_TEST\"
Dim strRes as String
strRes = modFileFolder.AvailableDirPath(txtPath)
```

What happens after getting return value was txtPath also changed. But If I modified it to

```
AvailableDirPath(ByVal strBase as String) As String
```

Then, txtPath is not changed.

I think Default parameter takes as ByVal but why it takes as ByRef?

Comment: Default in basic is byref. It more memory efficient and programmers learn not to modify parameters.

Comment: Yeah, You are correct! I saw somethere it says default is ByVal....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark mentioned, the default was ByRef. So if you do not intend to modify the arguments then you will need to explicitly define ByVal in the parameters.

Here is the link to explained by MS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/array-argument-must-be-byref